# How to remove duplicate active class from bootstrap tab <li> tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used two menu's to display the tab-pane (bootstrap). But it creates duplicate active link for `<li>` tag.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2j9c/1/

there should have only one active class for `<li>` for last active link. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a little part of JS, like this :

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
});
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/g2j9c/2/**

Answer (score 1):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2j9c/3/)

Use the following snippet,

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $('.nav li').not(parent).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For material design

```
$('a.list-group-item').click(function () {
    var actives = $(this).closest('ul').find('a.active');
    actives.not($(this)).removeClass('active');
});
```